# Magento 1.9 - cart page and checkout page blank

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, shared-hosting

The cart and checkout page was showing but suddenly became blank. All the side bar, header, footer are showing, just the content of the page itself refuse to show.

I checked the error log file and it shows,

PHP Startup: unable to load dynamic library 'usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mysqli.so : cannot open shared object file : no such file or directory in unknown on line 0

Comment: This is not issue with magento. It is issue with your PHP library. are u using xampp or stand alone linux PHP package?

Comment: I'm using a shared hosting

Comment: your answer is irrelevant to my question..

Comment: I'm Using Linux.